# How to extract information from text using regexes in Python?

Tags: python, regex, text-formatting

I have the following input. I want to parse it to a CSV delimited string. I can get the SKUs through regex patterns, but as I am new to regex parsing, I don't know complex patterns. It would be nice if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks!

```
    charset="iso-8859-1"


BODY {


}



TD {



}



TH {


}



H1 {


}

TABLE,IMG,A {


}

**PO Number:** 35102


**Ship To:**  


Georgie Clements



6902 Stonegate Drive

Odessa, TX 79765



432-363-8459


SKU



Product



Qty


JJ-Rug-Zebra-PK



Zebra Pink Rug



1

JJ-Zebra-PK-Twin-4



Zebra Pink 4 Piece Twin Comforter Set



1



JJ-TwinSheets-Zebra-PK



Zebra Pink 3 Piece Twin Sheet Set



1




JJ-Memo-Zebra-PK



Zebra Pink Memory Board



1
```

I want it to format like this:

```
PONumber, Shipping info, SKU, Product, Qty
'35102', '[ShipToAddress]', 'JJ-Rug-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Rug', '1'
'35102', '[ShipToAddress]', 'JJ-Zebra-PK-Twin-4', 'Zebra Pink 4 Piece Twin Comforter Set', '1'
'35102', '[ShipToAddress]', 'JJ-TwinSheets-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink 3 Piece Twin Sheet Set', '1'
'35102', '[ShipToAddress]', 'JJ-Memo-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Memory Board', '1'
```

The current code is the following:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w*JJ-\S*)') 

pos = 0 
    while True: 
        match = pattern.search(msgStr, pos) 
        if not match: 
            break 
        a = match.start() 
        e = match.end() 
        print ' %2d : %2d = %s' % (a, e-1, msgStr[a:e]) 
        pos = e
```

Comment: What does your regex look like so far?

Comment: Also, a single regex is not suitable for this problem. It requires parsing approach that has state. Each line has to be evaluated to determine if you are now capturing a different set of data.

Comment: pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w*JJ-\S*)')
          
          pos = 0
          while True:
            match = pattern.search(msgStr, pos)
            if not match:
              break
            a = match.start()
            e = match.end()
            print ' %2d : %2d = %s' % \
              (a, e-1, msgStr[a:e])
            pos = e

Comment: I think JSon might be more appropriate here. Also, 'shipping info' doesn't appear anywhere in the data.

Comment: Where are you getting this data and can you get a more useful source?

Comment: it doesn't matter regex or JSON, the thing is how can I convert it to the required formatting? FYI the Shipping Info is what we have **Ship To:** block, If JSON is the right approach, how I can convert the text into JSON

Comment: The suggestion was not to convert this to JSON. The question is "can you get this data in a json format to start"?

Comment: I get the data from our FTP, our client send this data in the format as is nothing I can do to change the way it is being sent, and neither I can ask them to change the formatting of it, now thats a challenge to format it to the required formatting so my cron process can sniff the resultant csv and save it to the database.

Comment: If it was in json format I did not had any need tp come here and post this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, not using regular expressions:

```
s = "(your data as a single multiline string)"

datalines = lambda s: [ln for ln in (line.strip() for line in s.splitlines()) if ln]

_, _, po_number, _, rem = s.split('**')
shipto, data = rem.split('SKU', 1)

po_number = datalines(po_number)[0]
shipto    = '\n'.join(datalines(shipto))
data      = datalines(data)[2:]

res = [[po_number, shipto, sku, prod, qty] for sku,prod,qty in zip(*([iter(data)]*3))]
```

which gives the final result

```
[
    ['35102', 'Georgie Clements\n6902 Stonegate Drive\nOdessa, TX 79765\n432-363-8459', 'JJ-Rug-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Rug', '1'],
    ['35102', 'Georgie Clements\n6902 Stonegate Drive\nOdessa, TX 79765\n432-363-8459', 'JJ-Zebra-PK-Twin-4', 'Zebra Pink 4 Piece Twin Comforter Set', '1'],
    ['35102', 'Georgie Clements\n6902 Stonegate Drive\nOdessa, TX 79765\n432-363-8459', 'JJ-TwinSheets-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink 3 Piece Twin Sheet Set', '1'],
    ['35102', 'Georgie Clements\n6902 Stonegate Drive\nOdessa, TX 79765\n432-363-8459', 'JJ-Memo-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Memory Board', '1']
```

**Edit:** second data file returns

```
[
    ['35104', 'Angelica Alvarado\n669 66th St.\nSpringfield, OR 97478\n5412322525', 'JJ-CribSheet-Cheetah-PK-PRT', 'Cheetah Pink Print Microsuede Crib Sheet', '1']
]
```

which on inspection appears to be correct?

---

**Final Summary**: I discovered that he was using html2text to convert the html email to text, then trying to parse it. The solution was to instead parse the html directly using BeautifulSoup, taking advantage of the page structure to identify the fields he wanted.

Comment: its giving me error here's the dump Something went wrong! <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processUploads.py", line 39, in <module>
    _, _, po_number, _, rem = s.split('**')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @AMalik: it looks like your data string doesn't contain any '**'s?

Comment: Oh sorry for that yeah it seems that first few files done have data in em, I will put a condition to skip them, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: ok this seems strange as all the files have got those '**' I just dumped all that data in to a single txt file with defining [START FILE] and [END FILE] tags and found out they all got those characters there.. Where can i paste the sample data?

Comment: I have updated your answer with the sample data in it, please note that the [START FILE] and [END FILE] tags were added for comparison, they will be not in real data

Comment: @AMalik: both of those work properly for me (once I split them back into separate files). With the `boundary` tags, it looks like you're splitting these out of a multipart/mime email?

Comment: yup but thanks for everything mate that was very helpful of you I will take closer look at the code and try to get it running. Cheers!

Comment: I have tested your approach but still have no luck.. Do you want me to provide you with anything else?

Comment: @AMalik: if you want to email me some of the original files (especially the ones that are giving you trouble), I'll take another look at it - hugh_bothwell at hotmail dot com.

Comment: I have sent you the files needed on your email. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this kind of input data is better suited for a stateful parsing approach as opposed to regex solutions. There are certain lines which indicate the parsing state should change to capture a new set of data.

Ideally first off you would see if this data source is available in JSON instead of what I presume is a webscraping of HTML. Having a JSON source will make this process trivial since the data will already be in an object format.

If your only option is to work with this line-by-line source, you would be best off either using something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), or if that is considered overkill for your needs, you could loop over the lines and check each one to see if you should start or stop collecting a type of data until the next token.

As a last resort, you could run multiple regex patterns over the entire input. The reason you have to run it over the entire input is because your data spans lines. A basic regex for capturing the SKU/Product/Qty might be:

```
re.findall(r'(JJ-[\w-]+)\n+(.*?)\n+(\d+)\n', dataStr)
#[('JJ-Rug-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Rug', '1'),
# ('JJ-Zebra-PK-Twin-4', 'Zebra Pink 4 Piece Twin Comforter Set', '1'),
# ('JJ-TwinSheets-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink 3 Piece Twin Sheet Set', '1'),
# ('JJ-Memo-Zebra-PK', 'Zebra Pink Memory Board', '1')]
```

This would find each 3 lines containing those patterns and return a list of tuples. I really don't recommend the regex approach but its an option.

Other regexes:

```
re.search(r'\*{2}PO Number:\*{2}\s(\d+)\n', dataStr)
#('35102',)

re.search(r'\*{2}Ship To:\*{2}\s+(.*?)\s+SKU', dataStr, re.DOTALL)
#('John Doe\n6902 Stonegate Drive\nOdessa, TX 79\n000-000-0000',)
```

You can see how you would just need to build individual regexes for each bit of data.

Comment: I think your regex doesn't work as you are looking for SKUs ending with -PK only but if you see the data up there in the source i provided, that's not the case and pattern fails..

Comment: Just remove the `-PK`. You can see how this becomes a game of "exact pattern" vs the parsing approach of "This line indicates we are now taking product data, so take the next 3 lines as a product"

Comment: I would change the source as it was and want you to run your pattern on it you will notice yourself what i am referring to

Comment: I just updated my pattern. All you needed was to allow multuple newlines with \n+. My last pattern update worked fine to account for SKU not ending in PK. The issue was the multiple newlines between each line. That is fixed.

Comment: here's the fixed pattern thanks to RegExr (\b\w*JJ-\S*)\s+(\b\w+\s)+\s+(\d)+

Comment: Make sure you mark RegExr as the accepted answer. He gave you the best help! :-) Honestly, there is really no way for me to know all the possible character cases and pattens based on one input file. I figured you would have to modify the pattern ranges to suit. This is a very localized question.